# Compiling webkit using nightly source

Tags: webkit

I'm just getting started with webkit & I wanted to perform a build myself first. I am a little confused as to how to compile using [nightly sources of webkit](http://nightly.webkit.org). The build instructions on the main webkit site says to have the whole SVN tree to perform a full build. But the nightly source only includes a small subset of that tree.

So is the case that you still have to have the whole tree but if you want the latest, you just download the latest nightly source & just drop it in your local tree? Or can you actually just use the nightly source to get a compiled version?

Answer (score 1):

http://www.webkit.org/building/build.html should get you started. See the linked http://www.webkit.org/building/checkout.html for how to get the full WebKit source.